# Rolling 30 days of data from Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I have this query:

```
SELECT ga_channelGrouping, ga_sourceMedium,ga_campaign, SUM(ga_sessions) as sessions,
SUM(ga_sessionDuration)/SUM(ga_sessions) as avg_sessionDuration, 
SUM(ga_users)as Users, SUM(ga_newUsers)as New_Users, SUM(ga_bounces)/SUM(ga_sessions) 
AS ga_bounceRate, SUM(ga_pageviews)/SUM(ga_sessions)as pageViews_per_sessions, 
SUM( ga_transactions)/SUM(ga_sessions) AS ga_conversionRate 


FROM db.table 

group by ga_channelGrouping, ga_sourceMedium,ga_campaign
```

How do I find rolling 30 days of data from Big Query. My `DATE` column value is of this format: `2018-06-19 11:00:00 UTC`

Comment: What do you mean by "rolling 30 days of data"? Do you want to query only over the past 30 days?

Comment: Yes yes- exactly past 30 days. Like 30 days of window. @alamoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DATE_ADD` or `DATE_SUB` functions to shift date values and `TIMESTAMP_ADD`, `TIMESTAMP_SUB` to shift timestamp values.

So you could try:

```
SELECT ga_channelGrouping, ga_sourceMedium,ga_campaign, SUM(ga_sessions) as sessions,
SUM(ga_sessionDuration)/SUM(ga_sessions) as avg_sessionDuration, 
SUM(ga_users)as Users, SUM(ga_newUsers)as New_Users, SUM(ga_bounces)/SUM(ga_sessions) 
AS ga_bounceRate, SUM(ga_pageviews)/SUM(ga_sessions)as pageViews_per_sessions, 
SUM( ga_transactions)/SUM(ga_sessions) AS ga_conversionRate 


FROM db.table 

WHERE your_date_column >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 24*30 HOUR)

group by ga_channelGrouping, ga_sourceMedium,ga_campaign
```

The `TIMESTAMP_SUB` doesn't take `DAY` as an interval, so here we've done `24*30` hours to go back 30 days.

---

**EDIT**: If you want to roll back 30 days regardless of the time of the day you can do the following:

```
WHERE your_date_column >= TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 24*30 HOUR), DAY)
```

OR

```
WHERE CAST(your_date_column AS DATE) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you so much @alamoot. It worked for me!

Comment: @user9645175 I added the edit portion to the end of the answer in case you're interested to roll back 30 days, regardless of the time of the day.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I find rolling 30 days of data from Big Query. My DATE column value is of this format:  2018-06-19 11:00:00 UTC

First, I wanted to point out that `aggregating last 30 days` is **quite different** from `rolling 30 days` - so below answer is actually focusing on `rolling 30 days` vs. `just last 30 days`

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and assumes that your date column is named `your_date_column` and is of TIMESTAMP data type

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  your_date_column, -- data type of TIMESTAMP with value like 2018-06-19 11:00:00 UTC
  ga_channelGrouping, 
  ga_sourceMedium,
  ga_campaign, 
  SUM(ga_sessions) OVER(win) AS sessions,
  (SUM(ga_sessionDuration) OVER(win))/(SUM(ga_sessions) OVER(win)) AS avg_sessionDuration, 
  SUM(ga_users) OVER(win) AS Users, 
  SUM(ga_newUsers) OVER(win) AS New_Users, 
  (SUM(ga_bounces) OVER(win))/(SUM(ga_sessions) OVER(win)) AS ga_bounceRate, 
  (SUM(ga_pageviews) OVER(win))/(SUM(ga_sessions) OVER(win)) AS pageViews_per_sessions, 
  (SUM(ga_transactions) OVER(win))/(SUM(ga_sessions) OVER(win)) AS ga_conversionRate 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WINDOW win AS (
  PARTITION BY ga_channelGrouping, ga_sourceMedium, ga_campaign
  ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(DATE(your_date_column)) 
  RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)
```

For you to understand how it works - try and play with below dummy example (for simplicity it does rolling `3` days)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 value, TIMESTAMP '2018-06-19 11:00:00 UTC' your_date_column UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-20 11:00:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2018-06-21 11:00:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '2018-06-22 11:00:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, '2018-06-23 11:00:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, '2018-06-24 11:00:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, '2018-06-25 11:00:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, '2018-06-26 11:00:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, '2018-06-27 11:00:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, '2018-06-28 11:00:00 UTC' 
)
SELECT 
  your_date_column, 
  value, 
  SUM(value) OVER(win) rolling_value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WINDOW win AS (ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(DATE(your_date_column)) RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
ORDER BY your_date_column
```

where result is

```
Row your_date_column        value   rolling_value    
1   2018-06-19 11:00:00 UTC 1       1    
2   2018-06-20 11:00:00 UTC 2       3    
3   2018-06-21 11:00:00 UTC 3       6    
4   2018-06-22 11:00:00 UTC 4       9    
5   2018-06-23 11:00:00 UTC 5       12   
6   2018-06-24 11:00:00 UTC 6       15   
7   2018-06-25 11:00:00 UTC 7       18   
8   2018-06-26 11:00:00 UTC 8       21   
9   2018-06-27 11:00:00 UTC 9       24   
10  2018-06-28 11:00:00 UTC 10      27
```